# sp_executesql not setting a variable correctly in a dynamic sql query in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql, sp-executesql

In query below, I am trying to set the value of `@productsExist` using a dynamic query that is executed by `sp_executesql` in SQL Server 2012. The problem is that even though the table `@tableName` exists and contains records, the value of `productsExist` is always `null` after the dynamic query is executed.

**Question**: Why is the query returning null for `@productsExist` even when the the table exists and has records?

```
DECLARE @productsExist INT;
DECLARE @countQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'IF OBJECT_ID(@tableName, N''U'') IS NOT NULL 
                     begin  select top(1) @productsExist = 1  from ' + @tableName + ' end';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @countQuery, N'@tableName varchar(500),@productsExist INT',
              @tableName = @tableName,
              @productsExist = @productsExist;

select @productsExist as ProductsExist--returns always a NULL value for ProductsExist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `@productsExist` parameter as [`OUTPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx):

> **[ OUT | OUTPUT ]**
>
> Indicates that the parameter is an output parameter

```
DECLARE @productsExist INT
        ,@tableName SYSNAME = 'tab';

DECLARE @countQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
N'IF OBJECT_ID(@tableName, N''U'') IS NOT NULL 
  begin  select top(1) @productsExist = 1  from ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ' end';

EXECUTE dbo.sp_executesql 
        @countQuery,
        N'@tableName SYSNAME ,@productsExist INT OUTPUT',     -- here
        @tableName = @tableName,
        @productsExist = @productsExist OUTPUT;               -- here

SELECT @productsExist as ProductsExist;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/03e17/4/0)**</kbd>

---

If there is no records in specified table the `@productsExist` will return `NULL`. If you want 1 for existing and 0 for no records use:

```
DECLARE @countQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
N'IF OBJECT_ID(@tableName, N''U'') IS NOT NULL 
  BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM '+ QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ')
       SELECT @productsExist = 1
    ELSE 
       SELECT @productsExist = 0
  END';
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5adb9/11/0)**</kbd>

Result:

```
table not exists          => NULL
table exists no records   => 0
table exists >= 1 records => 1
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks. Is using `SYSNAME` instead of varchar for `@tableName` a better option?

Comment: @Sunil [SYSNAME](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191240%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is just alias for `NVARCHAR(128)`. I use it because it is a good practice, but varchar will also work(to 128 chars).

Comment: I found `QUOTENAME` something new but very useful since it places square brackets around the table name. I have never come across this till your answer. Thanks.